# HTTP GET/POST request from within a solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity

I am working on a problem that requires a solidity smart contract to make an HTTP GET/POST request to a website. The scenario is given below

-A simple text file 'abc.txt' with a 32-byte string is placed on a webserver

-Entity 1 calls a smart contract with a parameter which is a 'website URL/abc.txt'
-When invoked by Entity 1, Smart-contract retrieves the value stored in 'website URL/abc.txt', do some operations on it and store it on the blockchain.

In short, I want the Smart Contract, when invoked, to retrieve the token from the website.  I know that Ethereum blockchain cannot interact with the outside world and the possible solution that I am looking into is Oracles but the issue is that I don't want to involve a 3rd party in my solution? Is there any better way to achieve this desired workflow without affecting the decentralization?

Comment: the smart contract can't access outside world and an Oracle is a centralized agent. So, the only way to do what you want is to create your own peer to peer network

Comment: The best way to do it is to create few oracles to decentralize things a little bit.